# Get all entities of a type as a Map<Key, Entitiy>

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

When using `ofy().load().type(SomeEntity.class).ids(id_collection);`, you get the result as a `Map<String, SomeEntity>` (assuming the key-type is `String`).

Is it possible to get such a mapping of `Key -> Entity` for **all** entries of a given type, not just the ones with matching ids?

**Background**: Currently, I'm doing something like this (Pseudo-Code):

```
foreach operation: o {
  List<SomeEntitiy> affected = ofy.load(o.affectedEntities)
  foreach affected: a{
    a.performOperation(o)
  }
  ofy.save(affected)
}
```

It's possible that one entity is affected by multiple operations, so I'd like to just fetch all entities once, perform the operations on the affected ones and then store them once.

Answer (score 1):

That method is just a convenience method, shorthand for keys() with a bunch of keys constructed from that type and set of ids. Take a look at the implementation in `LoadTypeImpl`.

By subclassing a few of the Objectify command classes, you could add your own overload. Or just use the keys() method.